# Dependency Injection In DoFns for Apache Beam Golang

Tags: go, apache-beam

I want to be able to unit test my apache beam dofns by mocking functions a dofn invokes.

Say I am defining a structural dofn and would like to dynamically define a sub-function invoked in the body of the dofn.

Using a separate receiver function on the struct causes serialization issues (and may constitute a closure? which is [not allowed](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#user-code-serializability))

#### DoFn definition

```
func init() {
  register.DoFn3x0[string, func(string), func(string)](&structuralDoFnExample{})
}

type structuralDoFnExample struct {
  OtherReceiverFunction func(...) (...)
}

func (fn *structuralDoFnExample) ProcessElement(exampleInput string, emit, errs func(string)) {
  ...
  fn.OtherReceiverFunction(...)
  ...
}
```

##### DoFn Invocation

```
emitted, errors := beam.ParDo2(s.Scope("something"), &structuralDoFnExample{
    OtherReceiverFunction: ReceiverFunctionImplementation,
  }, inputPCol)
```

#### Error

`unable to convert unsupported type func(...) (...) to schema`

Is there a way around this limitation? Is there some other way to define a dofn where I can use dependency injection? My motivation is to enable unit testing:

1. Directly on the dofn itself that doesn't invoke real services (i.e. mocking ReceiverFunctionImplementation)
2. Run pipeline without invoking real services (i.e. mocking ReceiverFunctionImplementation)

Comment: For context: [this article](https://medium.com/@gauravmishra_82578) accomplishes an almost identical goal in the java sdk via interfaces, and my issue is not fixed by registering a `ReceiverFunctionImplementation `